# how to bind kendo datetime picker with knockout observable element?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-kendo, kendo-datetimepicker

I have a observable property which should be bound to kendo datetime picker. The property has a  default value. When the observable property is bound to kendo datetime picker, the value should be shown. On update of date and time through the picker the observable has to be updated.

The html code is:

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
   <input class="form-control"  />  
</div>
```

and the script code is:

```
var vm = {
            maintenanceDateTime: ko.observable(),
};

$("#datetimepicker1").kendoDateTimePicker({
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm', 
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
    value: vm.maintenanceDateTime()
});
```

I am not able to get this working. Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Knockout-Kendo](http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/Calendar.html) (There exist nuget package).

Other option would be create [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can i have a working example? i m new to knockout and kendo.

Comment: Yes i did go through this example( [link]http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/DateTimePicker.html ). How can i set the format for the date and time?

Comment: link only answer, should add it to comments instead or provide some actual code

Comment: Is this the only way to get this working? I am having issues, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23719219/kendo-ui-mvvm-datepicker-allow-the-value-to-be-empty